# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" when working with Apache POI, excel, and eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
public static String read1(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    String value = new String();
    HSSFWorkbook wb = null;

    try {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(Words1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("SAT");
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex - 1);
    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colIndex - 1);

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

    return value;
}
```

Then I have a main class that tells the program to use this method. The problem when I run it is 
`"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

at Outline.read1(Outline.java:34)

at Outline.main(Outline.java:55)"

where line 34 is this(in the snippet above):

```
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("SAT");
```

and line 55 is the part that tells the program to go to this method, which is:

```
String val=read1(rowIndex,colIndex);
```

I can't, for the life of me, find the reason why this won't run. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
wb= new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(Words1));
```

probably throws an exception, but you don't notice because you are not handling it. And then `wb` stays `null` and you get a `NullPointerException` when calling

```
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("SAT");
```

Try adding `e.printStackTrace();` to the catch block to see if there is an exception thrown:

```
try {
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(Words1));
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Now it highlights the part where I added that and it says "Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected instead", what does that mean?

Comment: did you add it inside the catch block?

Comment: like this try
   {
    wb= new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(Words1));
   } catch (Exception e.printStackTrace();)
    {
    }

Comment: Oh, ok, gotcha, now it says The system cannot find the file specified, I can figure that out. Thanks!